# `Plus` wrongly applies `OneIdentity` to eradicate itself in `Plus[Power[_, 2] ..]`, unreproducible

Tags: pattern-matching, attributes, built-in-symbols

I was trying to match some polynomials, but this is weird:

```
Plus[Power[x, 2], Power[y, 2]]~MatchQ~Plus[Power[_, 2] ..]
SetAttributes[f, Attributes@Plus]
f[Power[x, 2], Power[y, 2]]~MatchQ~f[Power[_, 2] ..]
```

Despite `f` having all of the same attributes as `Plus`, the expressions match only when it is used

> `False` `True`

I found this is the root of the problem:

```
Plus[Power[_, 2] ..] // FullForm
```

gives `Repeated[Power[Blank[],2]]`, the `Plus` entirely disappears, while

```
f[Power[_, 2] ..] // FullForm
```

gives `f[Repeated[Power[Blank[],2]]]` as I would expect.

I understand many built-in symbols escape the standard evaluation procedure anyways, so that not all of their behaviour is readily understandable from their `Attributes` etc. Obviously, `Plus` wrongly applies something like `OneIdentity` in this case, causing it to be removed. A user-defined symbol such as `f` doesn't do it here.

Is this a bug?

Comment: Isn't only this `f[x_] := x` enough to replicate `Plus` in this case? P.s. `HoldPattern[Plus[Power[_, 2] ..]]` will work btw.

Comment: To add to Kuba's remark: Is it `OneIdentity` or simply "`Plus[x]` is `x`" as stated in the docs for `Plus`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As pointed out in comments, this is caused by

> `Plus[x]` is `x`

Here are some workarounds

```
Plus[Power[x, 2], Power[y, 2]]~MatchQ~Verbatim[Plus][Power[_, 2] ..]
Plus[Power[x, 2], Power[y, 2]]~MatchQ~HoldPattern[Plus][Power[_, 2] ..]
Plus[Power[x, 2], Power[y, 2]]~MatchQ~HoldPattern[Plus[Power[_, 2] ..]]
```

all giving `True` as expected.