# A pattern involving Times

Tags: pattern-matching, argument-patterns

If I define (this is 10.0.0.0)

```
w[x : Times[xs__]] := {x, xs}
w[x : h[xs__]] := {x, xs}
```

`Definition[w]` gives me

```
w[x : h[xs__]] := {x, xs}
w[x : xs__] := {x, xs}
```

and the `Times` got lost. The two equations got reversed —because the one involving the `Times` did not see it and is more general than the other.

Is this expected behaviour? The second equation given by `Definition` definitely does something difference from my first equation, as `xs` matches the product and not the sequence of its factors.

My guess is this comes from `Times` being `Flat`. How does one do what the above definition tried to do?

Comment: `w[x_Times] := {x, Sequence @@ x}` does seem to work.

Comment: Similarly, something like `w[x : (Times|ThisWillNeverMatch)[xs__]] := {x, xs}` does do the trick (and `ThisWillNeverMatch` can be meaningfully replaced by `Except[_]`, I guess)

Comment: `Times[xs__]` immediately evaluates to `Sequence[xs]`. Try this: `Clear@w;
w[x : HoldPattern[Times[xs__]]] := {x, xs}; 
w[x : h[xs__]] := {x, xs}` or this: `Clear@w;
SetAttributes[w, HoldAll];
w[x : Times[xs__]] := {x, xs};
w[x : h[xs__]] := {x, xs}`. In either case, then do `?w`.

Comment: Why is the pattern evaluated?

Comment: I don't remember!

Comment: By the way, `w[x_Times] := {x, Sequence @@ x}` only works if the input is symbolic, `w[1*2*3*4]` evaluates to `w[24]`. Even doing `SetAttributes[w, HoldAll]` doesn't work.

Comment: Related: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/124215/4999

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Consider

```
Clear[w]
w[x : HoldPattern[Times[xs__]]] := {x, xs}
Definition @ w
```

> `w[x : HoldPattern[Times[xs__]]] := {x, xs}`

w[a b c]

> `{a b c, a, b, c}`

Does this approach work for you?

Comment: Yup. This this what I ended up doing.