# Commutativity of Times and pattern matching

Tags: pattern-matching

I understand that Attributes of Times make a bit non intuitive the Pattern Matching of its arguments.
However I do not understand why this gives False:

```
MatchQ[Times[a, b, c], Times[___, b, ___]] 
False
```

Can you explain it to me?

Comment: You need the pattern `HoldPattern[Times[___, b, ___]]` instead. If you look at the `FullForm` of `Times[___, b, ___]` you'll see that the attributes of `Times` mucked up the pattern.

Comment: Related: [(156282)](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/156282)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Times[___,b,___] // FullForm
```

> Times[b,Power[BlankNullSequence[],2]]

```
MatchQ[Times[a, b, c], HoldPattern[Times[___, b, ___]]]
```

> True

or

```
MatchQ[Times[a, b, c], Unevaluated[Times[___, b, ___]]]
```

> True